# How to make disappear object in animation without visibility for Game Engines?

Tags: animation, unity, visibility

Toggling "eye" icon in animation is not working in Unity. I found some alternative solutions such as scale down to super little or move it to very very far away.

Actually I already did second option in many models that I made before, however because of interpolation in Game Engine(Unity), I can clearly see the object moving a very little time.

Making disappearing object is really really useful technic for animations, especially making first person perspective animation, however I always faced this issue.

Is there an another way to hide object that I didn't tried? Or is there a way to hide the object even animation interpolated from another 3d prorgrams such as Unity Game Engine?

Comment: This is supposed to be a place for questions about Blender, not Unity. You can enable or disable rendering of objects in Unity or you can make them inactive. You have not done any reasearch before asking - a simple Google search will answer your question.

Comment: @MartinZ It's about Unity yes, but it also related about Blender too. I can hide object from Unity with variety ways, but I can't edit in Animation directly. So that's why I'm asking here to find better solution how to hide object. And I already searched on Google about this and there was no helpful information.

Comment: @MartinZ Also I said "Game Engines" in title that's because it will also happens from another Game Engines. Unity is just example to describe my situtation, I'm pretty sure this will happens other programs, not just Unity or any kind of Game Engine. Many people using Blender for making games, and it's related both Blender and Game Engines. There might be way to solve in Unity itself, however it could be also solve be Blender and that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @MartinZ Also disabling object in Unity is really not helpful, because it's not simple situtation. In Unity, I can't edit animation directly, I have to duplication animation clip to edit. Do this every animation clip in every object is really waste of my time. There are bunch of way to "hide" object in Unity, to work with them, I have to something really repetitive, tedious, and hard to maintain jobs. What if I changed the animation, or add new animation clip? I just want to know that it could be done in Blender, not coming from Unity for better development.

Comment: @MartinZ Before pressing down vote, be sure the question is not supposed to be here. I don't think that it must be 100% Blender related issue. Is there any clear notices that only question 100% Blender related? There are already hunders of Unity related questions in here. Include other stuffs, like Unreal Engine, or any kind of program that possibly can collaborate with Blender, maybe much more. Those are situations that do something with Blender, not just only in the Blender.

Comment: @MartinZ One more say, I'm not asking how to with Unity. Please read the title again, what I'm asking is: "Disappear object withtout visibility". This is "100% Blender related issue", for Unity is just final purpose. So, still should it be not worth to question here? I just want to know another way to hide object in animation in Blender so I could try in Unity too.

Comment: Reason I mentioned about Unity and Game Engines, just because give some more information to people who might be answer my question. I'm not asking how to do with Unity, or whatever, I'm just asking other way to hide object I could try in Blender. What I tried are moving somewhere far away with very fast speed and scale down to zero scale, but both are not perfect solution in my case, because Unity interpolates animation so it doesn't happen immediately. So I found another way, using visibility but it's just not working in Unity because doesn't support it so I try to find another way I can try.

Comment: Visibility in Blender is controlled with object's 'hide' and 'hide_render' properties that are animatable. One can animate various shader properties to make objects invisible as well. If Constant interpolation is chosen any keyframe will change values instantly without any visible interpolation. The functionality is complete and works as it is supposed to work inside Blender. Apparently animated visibility cannot be exported with FBX format and be imported to Unity. Therefore this problem will require a solution inside Unity.

Comment: @MarinZ So that's why I'm asking hide object without using visibility in Blender. I'm not asking how to work with it.